# How to use PHPmailer? Help me with its API

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have created a PHP page, whereby having the page to send automatically to user, i tried using PHPMailer but it only says "SMTP ERROR: cannot access host **or somthing like that** "

here's my code:

```
PHPMailer x = new PHPMailer();
x->isSMTP();
x->Host = myhost;
x->Port = myport;
x->AddAddress(recipientAddress);
x->From = myEmail;
x->Username = username;
x->Password = password;
x.Send();
```

Comment: Does it *literally* say "or somthing like that"? 'I have an error: it says "error", or something.' Y'know, the error message is actually supposed to tell you a possible cause. Or something.

Comment: sorry.. i forgot the whole error msg.. thats just an addon i put..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is quick fix of your code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->setCharset = "UTF-8";
$mail->Host = "localhost";
//    $mail->Port = "587"; you don't need it now 
    $mail->AddAddress("recipientAddress");
    $mail->setFrom = "myEmail";
    $mail->Subject = "Subject";
    $mail->Username = "username";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                           // 1 = errors and messages
                           // 2 = messages only
    
    $mail->Send();
```

so now you would get  more debug messages and track your errors and fix them :)

update : okay that is easy :

The function $mail->IsMail(); indicates that the letter must be sent using mail() function. Other methods are:

> IsSendmail - via sendmail command.
>
> IsQmail - directly via qMail MTA.
>
> IsSMTP - via SMTP server.

Comment: thanks.. ill be trying that later... but the problem still stands... my host is my domain, my port is unspecified i dont know why..T_T but this is the closest thing ive seen to my problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `isSMTP` line so it will use the mail settings configured in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This looks that your SMTP settings *on the www server* are wrong.

Check if you can send the e-mail with the SMTP configuration you specified - if not:

- *is* there a SMTP server running on `myhost`:`myport`?
- Does it listen on the interface you're using to talk to it?
- Is it configured to accept mail *from* your host?
- Is it configured to accept mail *for* the recipients?